# HIVE query to get first user activity entry in each column

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table like:

```
id   email_sent email_opened  ad_clicked ts
1001 1          0             0         2017-05-01 02:40:00.0
1001 1          1             0         2017-07-01 02:40:00.0
1001 1          0             0         2017-08-01 02:40:00.0
1001 1          1             0         2017-09-01 02:40:00.0
1001 1          1             1         2017-10-01 02:40:00.0
```

Required Output:

```
user_id  first_email_sent       first_email_opened     first_ad_clicked
1001     2017-05-01 02:40:00.0  2017-07-01 02:40:00.0  2017-10-01 02:40:00.0
```

I am using below query to get this result:

> ```
>  select id,
>         min(case when email_sent = 1 then ts end)as first_email_sent,
>         min(case when email_opened = 1 then ts end)as email_opened, 
>         min(case when ad_clicked = 1 then ts end)as ad_clicked 
> from adcamp group by id;
> ```

Is there any better query ?

Comment: This is fine. Why is the hesitation?

Comment: Thanks Dudu. Just wanted to know that whether query can be optimized or not.